# Independent manipulate controls for part of list data

Tags: performance-tuning, dynamic

I have a graphic that consists of a ListPlot3D and a ListPointPlot3D. I want to only display part of the data for the second plot up to an nth index. That data is in `pointsDgd3DOpt`, so I select with `pointsDgd3DOpt[[;; nEndpoint]]`. That variable is in manipulate. But the first plot is slow and should not be updated when that variable changes. I've read in the "Advanced Manipulate Functionality" article how to do that in general (an inner dynamic). But that doesn't really work for me.

Without dynamic, it works but is slow:

```
pointsDgd3D = 
  Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], 
     "filter_small_space.txt"}], "CSV"];
pointsDgd3DOpt = 
  Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], 
     "filter_small_space_opt.txt"}], "CSV"];
func = Interpolation[pointsDgd3D];

Manipulate[
 Show[{
   ListPlot3D[pointsDgd3D,
    PlotRange -> Dynamic[{0, 3}]
    ],
   ListPointPlot3D[
    pointsDgd3DOpt[[;; nEndpoint]],
    PlotRange -> {0, 3}
    ]
   }],
 {nEndpoint, 1, 300, 1}
 ]
```

And with it spews "must be a valid array or a list of valid arrays" errors:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{
   ListPlot3D[pointsDgd3D,
    PlotRange -> {0, 3}
    ],
   ListPointPlot3D[
    Dynamic[pointsDgd3DOpt[[1 ;; nEndpoint]]],
    PlotRange -> {0, 3}
    ]
   }],
 {nEndpoint, 3, 300, 1}
 ]
```

Any pointers to what's happening?

EDIT: MWE:

```
pointsDgd3D = 
  Flatten[Table[{x, y, x*x + y*y}, {x, 0, 2, 0.2}, {y, 0, 2, 0.2}], 1];
pointsDgd3DOpt = RandomChoice[pointsDgd3D, 100];
func = Interpolation[pointsDgd3D];
Manipulate[
 Show[{
   ListPlot3D[pointsDgd3D],
   ListPointPlot3D[
    pointsDgd3DOpt[[1 ;; nEndpoint]],
    PlotStyle -> {Green, PointSize[0.1]}
    ]
   }],
 {nEndpoint, 3, 100, 1}
 ]
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the whole `ListPointPlot3D` with `Dynamic` instead of `pointsDgd3DOpt[[1 ;; nEndpoint]]`?

Comment: That throws "Could not combine the graphics objects in Show[...]"

Comment: If you can post a MWE that one can run,someone can show you now to do it. Your example is not possible to use, since you have `Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], 
     "filter_small_space.txt"}], "CSV"]` which uses your own local files.

Comment: Sure, I've edited one in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the "nested `Dynamic`" approach the tutorial suggests.

#### Dynamic Points special case

You can't just put `Dynamic` in the `ListPointPlot3D` but you can in `Graphics3D`.

```
Manipulate[Show[{
   Plot3D[func[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotPoints -> 50],
   Graphics3D[
    {Green, PointSize[0.1], 
     Dynamic@Point[pointsDgd3DOpt[[1 ;; nEndpoint]]]}
    ]
   }], {nEndpoint, 3, 100, 1}]
```

#### General nested Dynamics in 3D graphics

For more complicated, than a list of points, cases you can't put e.g `Dynamic@Plot3D[...` in `Show` but you can put `Graphics3D[{Dynamic@First@Plot3D[...]}]`.

Comment: This is simple and works perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I use the tick method for all my demos and Manipulate. It works all the time and for all problems. It is based on the event callback method used in standard GUI frameworks. An event happens (such as moving a slider, or clicking a button) then a local action is performed, only based on that one event. Then the GUI is updated. This means no other action needs to be done.

In this method, there is only *one* dynamic for the whole Manipulate that is tracked. So it is also very fast. When you want to update the main GUI (Manipulate expression), just tickle this one dynamic variable(the tick). It is boolean. So to tickle just flip it. In this method, you need to initialize all the dynamics you are using. Most can be done using `{{a,initalValue},None}` syntax.

Here is for your MWE

```
pointsDgd3D = 
  Flatten[Table[{x, y, x*x + y*y}, {x, 0, 2, 0.2}, {y, 0, 2, 0.2}], 1];
pointsDgd3DOpt = RandomChoice[pointsDgd3D, 100];
func = Interpolation[pointsDgd3D];

Manipulate[
 tick; (*must be here, so it is tracked*)

 Show[{p2, p1}],

 (*controls*)
 Grid[{{Manipulator[Dynamic[nEndpoint,
      {tick = Not[tick]; (*flip to update main GUI*)
        p1 = ListPointPlot3D[ (*update only this one plot*)
          pointsDgd3DOpt[[1 ;; nEndpoint]],
          PlotStyle -> {Green, PointSize[0.1]}];
        nEndpoint = #} &], {3, 100, 1}, ImageSize -> Tiny], 
    Dynamic[nEndpoint]}}],

 (*local dynamics below*)
 {{nEndpoint, 3}, None},
 {{p1, {}}, None},
 {{p2, ListPlot3D[pointsDgd3D]}, None}, (*second plot not affected*)
 {{tick, False}, None},

 TrackedSymbols :> {tick} (*tack only the tick*)
 ]
```

[image: animation]

ps. There are other ways to handle the problem at hand, but I use this method since it is simple and works for everything.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with `DynamicModule`

**Example**

```
DynamicModule[
 {data, sample, uLimit},

 data = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {1000, 3}];
 sample = RandomSample[data, 300];
 uLimit = 100;

 Column[{
   Slider[Dynamic@uLimit, {1, 300, 1}, ContinuousAction -> False],
   Dynamic @ Show[{
      ListPlot3D @ data,
      ListPointPlot3D[
       sample[[;; uLimit]],
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize @ 0.05]
       ]
      },
     Boxed -> False]
   },
  Alignment -> Center]
 ]
```

**Output**

[image: output]

Comment: This exhibits exactly the behavior I want to prevent: While moving the slider, the ListPlot gets undetailed. I assume that's because it's being reevaluated. I want the Plot to stay the same during slider changes.

Comment: As a workaround, amend `Slider` in a following way `Slider[Dynamic@uLimit, {1, 300, 1}, ContinuousAction -> False]`

Comment: But I DO want to have continuous action :D. The context is that this will be used in a presentation. The Plot is slow and I want to show the progress of the points on the surface (they're points of evaluation of an algorithm). There is a good solution here now though. Thanks anyways!